# Can an official N64 Rumble Pak be soldered to work without a battery?

Tags: nintendo-64, gaming-accessories

On the Wikipedia page for [Nintendo 64 accessories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nintendo_64_accessories), there is this statement about battery-free Rumble Paks:

> Battery-free Rumble Paks — Late in the N64's run, a few third-party companies made Rumble Paks that, instead of requiring batteries to work, drew power from the system. Curiously, it was possible to modify an official Rumble Pak using basic soldering in order to make it powered by the console.<sup>[citation needed]</sup>

Can an official Rumble Pak be soldered to be powered by the console and not require a battery?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about electrical engineering, not gaming.

Comment: @Frank could it be migrated to electronics stack overflow instead?

Comment: @RoijanEskor we don't have a migration functionality on Arqade - the OP would have to move it themselves.  We can only migrate posts to our meta.

Comment: @TimmyJim Can mods not migrate to other sites from this one?  I thought they could migrate regardless.  Users just can't vote to migrate unless it's an approved path (for this site, meta).  Is it different here?

Comment: @JMac I honestly don't know if mods can do that or not.

Comment: Moderators can do such migrations. We don't have an automatic migration path to anywhere but the Meta, since we need to handle each migration case by case. Mostly to make sure we don't just dump our garbage to other sites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There appears to be a few forums and videos showing that this is possible.  One video includes this one:

It seems all you have to do is de-solder a 60Ω resistor that is found within the Rumble Pak, and solder the same resistor into a different location.

An additional site that discusses this can be found [here](http://nintendoage.com/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=22&threadid=43419).  Using the image found on it, I illustrated what you need to do.  It doesn't seem that hard watching the video above.

[image: circuit board]

<sub><sub>[Image Source](http://nintendoage.com/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=22&threadid=43419) (modified)</sub></sub>

Note that it was pointed out in the video that having too many controllers with a modded Rumbled Pak could short out the console. It was suggested that you have no more than 2 controllers at a time with a Rumble Pak like this connected to the same console.

Comment: The only caveat I would add is, if your playing 4 player with rumble packs; everyone using this mod could lead to issues.  I was curious why this would even be battery powered if there was enough power in the system.  Apparently nintendo realized there isn't enough power to power the N64 and 4 rumble packs with the N64 power supply.  There's a chance something could break if you have too many modded controllers hooked up (or it may just not work).

Comment: @JMac at the end of the video I have in my answer, it says to avoid using more than 2 of these at a time on one console or it could short the console out. So yea, be careful.

Comment: I'd suggest adding it to the body just for reference.  Your screenshot basically shows the entire process anyways.